# How to update Data on UI

Tags: solidity, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, javascript

I have a UI thats connected to metamask

The UI updates all the Info now on address change and when metamask is enabled

How can i make my UI update every second? so it always shows accurate stats on UI?

This is the code i use for my UI

```
window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
    // Modern dapp browsers...
    if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
        try {
            await ethereum.enable();
            var accounts= await web3.eth.getAccounts();
            var option={from: accounts[0] };
            var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,address);
            const linkContract = new web3.eth.Contract(linkabi,linkContractAddress);

            const balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(accounts[0]).call();
            const myDivs = await contract.methods.dividendsOf(accounts[0]).call();
            const buyPrice = await contract.methods.buyPrice().call();
            const sellPrice = await contract.methods.sellPrice().call();
            const totalHolder = await contract.methods.totalHolder().call();

            var supply = await contract.methods.totalSupply().call();
            var linkBalance = await contract.methods.totalLinkBalance().call();

            const linkAccountBalance = await linkContract.methods.balanceOf(accounts[0]).call();

            const num = +Web3.utils.fromWei(linkAccountBalance);
            const link = +Web3.utils.fromWei(linkBalance);
            const linkies =+Web3.utils.fromWei(supply);
            const holdings = +Web3.utils.fromWei(balance);
            const divs = +Web3.utils.fromWei(myDivs);

            document.getElementById('linkAvailable').innerHTML = num.toFixed(3);
            document.getElementById('linkContractBalance').innerHTML = link.toFixed(3);
            document.getElementById('contractBalanceLinkies').innerHTML = linkies;
            document.getElementById('linkies-holding').innerHTML = holdings + ' LINKies';
            document.getElementById('myDividends').innerHTML = divs.toFixed(2) + ' LINK' ;
            document.getElementById('wallet').innerHTML = accounts;
            document.getElementById('buyPrice').innerHTML = buyPrice/100000000;
            document.getElementById('sellPrice').innerHTML = sellPrice/100000000;
            document.getElementById('totalPlayer').innerHTML = totalHolder;



            ethereum.on('accountsChanged', async (accounts) => {
              await ethereum.enable();
              var accounts= await web3.eth.getAccounts();
              var option={from: accounts[0] };
              var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,address);
              const linkContract = new web3.eth.Contract(linkabi,linkContractAddress);

              const balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(accounts[0]).call();
              const myDivs = await contract.methods.dividendsOf(accounts[0]).call();
              const buyPrice = await contract.methods.buyPrice().call();
              const sellPrice = await contract.methods.sellPrice().call();
              const totalHolder = await contract.methods.totalHolder().call();

              var supply = await contract.methods.totalSupply().call();
              var linkBalance = await contract.methods.totalLinkBalance().call();

              const linkAccountBalance = await linkContract.methods.balanceOf(accounts[0]).call();

              const num = +Web3.utils.fromWei(linkAccountBalance);
              const link = +Web3.utils.fromWei(linkBalance);
              const linkies =+Web3.utils.fromWei(supply);
              const holdings = +Web3.utils.fromWei(balance);
              const divs = +Web3.utils.fromWei(myDivs);

              document.getElementById('linkAvailable').innerHTML = num.toFixed(3);
              document.getElementById('linkContractBalance').innerHTML = link.toFixed(3);
              document.getElementById('contractBalanceLinkies').innerHTML = linkies;
              document.getElementById('linkies-holding').innerHTML = holdings + ' LINKies';
              document.getElementById('myDividends').innerHTML = divs.toFixed(2) + ' LINK' ;
              document.getElementById('wallet').innerHTML = accounts;
              document.getElementById('buyPrice').innerHTML = buyPrice/100000000;
              document.getElementById('sellPrice').innerHTML = sellPrice/100000000;
              document.getElementById('totalPlayer').innerHTML = totalHolder;
            })
        } catch (error) {
            // User denied account access...
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can set a timer and call the contract and update the page.

Comment: how can i call the emit function

Comment: What do you mean with emit function? For general programming question you will get faster answer in stackoverflow.com